# Expressing $4n+3$ as difference of two squares

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Is there a way to express $4n+3$ as a difference of two squares? For example, $4n=(n+1)^{2}-(n-1)^2$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any odd number can be written as the difference of two consecutive squares.  In this case, we have

$$(2n+2)^2-(2n+1)^2=(2n+2+2n+1)(2n+2-2n-1)=4n+3$$

Answer (score 0):

You can write $a^2-b^2$ as $(a+b)(a-b)$. Set $a+b=4n+3$ and $a-b=1$ then solve for $a$ and $b$